# Can I continue school for the PPL in another country in another flight school, if it is still inside EU?

Tags: easa-regulations, ppl, flight-school

I am attending flight school for PPL at the moment at a flight school in Italy.

Next year I will study in Germany. It is possible that I will not have finished the PPL until then. Now theoretically the university is still very near at my home place (3 hours with the car), so I could somehow manage to finish my license.

However, would it theoretically be possible to continue my license in Germany at another flight school? I can speak Italian, German and English fluently, so language wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I tagged it for EASA regulations since it is what applies within the EU

Comment: English requires proper nouns to be capitalized. :)

Answer (score 2):

Laws within the EU can vary, however I would ***assume*** it would be possible to carry on training in another country, however I am not sure.

The best way to know, would be to ask your flight school! :) 
They may know, and could contact the school you want to move to and work out a deal.

Best of luck

EDIT: In my country (Australia) it is possible to continue training overseas, even though we are not part of an EU style union.

EDIT 2: As I stated, if you currently undertake flight training, your instructor would know better than any online message board.